# Cannot remove() a row append() to a table

Tags: jquery

I have a table with several rows () and I use jQuery append() to add one more row to the table.
Then I try to delete that row with remove(), which is working fine with the original rows, and fail.

Please help. Thanks.

```
<table id="mybbbb" border="1" style="width:300px"><tbody>
    <tr><td>some text</td><td><div class="linksd">delete</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>some text</td><td><div class="linksd">delete</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>some text</td><td><div class="linksd">delete</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>some text</td><td><div class="linksd">delete</div></td></tr>
</tbody></table>

<div id="addRow">add row</div>

<script>
jQuery("#addRow").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#mybbbb > tbody:last").append("<tr><td>more text</td><td><div class='linksd'>delete</div></td></tr>");
});

jQuery(".linksd").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();
            return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link.  http://jsfiddle.net/twCd6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the newly created rows are not present in the DOM when the Javascript event listeners are assigned.

For jQuery 1.6 (as used in your fiddle) you can use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to listen past the original DOM creation point:

```
$('.linksd').live('click', function(event){
```

And for more modern versions of jQuery (`live` is deprecated now) you should use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.linksd', function(event){
```

Examples in the [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twCd6/12/) and change the jQuery version to see.

Comment: Good job. I just thinked about that, but you was first. +1

Answer (score -1):

There is no default behaviour for clicking on a div.

Remove `event.preventDefault();` and `return false` from your code like this, works for me.

```
jQuery(".linksd").click(function(event){   
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();   
});
```

Demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twCd6/17/)

Comment: OP is asking about the rows added by clicking "add row" not being able to be deleted - your solution doesn't change that.